# Why is there no oprofile in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, performance

I've upgraded a ubuntu server from 11.10 to 12.04.
The oprofile package i installed is missed.

As shown in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/oprofile/0.9.6-1.3ubuntu1, oprofile seems to be deleted from the deb repository.

Why is that? Should I manually install oprofile or wait it back soon?

Comment: 2009?... When I checked the website, the last activity was listed as Aug 2012. http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/oprofile/0.9.6-1.3ubuntu1

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653168

> Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2011 16:56:55 +0100
>
> Source: oprofile
>   Severity: serious
>
> oprofile seems like a candidate for removal:
>
> - Last maintainer upload in 2009
> - No followup to security or RC bugs from the maintainers
> - Low popcon
> - Alternatives exist (perf)
> - Depends on legacy libs (604366)
> - Broken wih current kernels (615964)
>
> Unless there're objections/fixes, I'll file a removal bug in a month.

Comment: I'm sorry but its not entirely true. The last release of Oprofile is from August 2012, and Oprofile now rely on perf itself to do the job, so perf is not an alternative but a dependency now.

May be the package need a maintainer and I perfectly understand why a non-maintained package should be removed. However, I think that Oprofile in itself should be there.

Besides, it is pretty easy and fast to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Debian is always looking for volunteers to maintain packages. And eventually, this seems like the best way to get packages (back) into Ubuntu. And the fact that there was no maintainer upload since 2009 is dated to Dec 2011, so the upstream release you mentioned happened after that. And an upstream release is different from a maintainer upload.
It would be nice to have Oprofile back in Debian (and Ubuntu), but it will probably not happen without a volunteer stepping up to maintain the package (not necessarily oprofile itself).